# Complicated SQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have inherited a DB that has products, where each product has attributes, which are organised in groups ,

I need to construct a query that allows a user to specify a bunch of attributes and return the products that have at least one match in each group.

So if a product has a color of blue, size: xl and collarshape is vneck, 
and a user chooses blue, green, vneck xl xxl, then the above product would match. If the product only had the color yellow it would not match

Below is the table structure..

E.g. colors :  blue, yellow, green,   sizes: xl xxl l s,  collarshape: vneck, crewneck

\ the products,

```
 CREATE TABLE products (
        id     integer,
        name    varchar(40),
        PRIMARY KEY(id)
    );
```

// join attributes and products

```
    CREATE TABLE attributes_products (
        product_id     integer,
        attibute_id integer 
    );
```

//  attributes
// e.g blue, yellow, green ,  xl, xxl, l, s ,vneck, crewneck

```
    CREATE TABLE attributes (
        id     integer,
        label varchar(40),
        attribute_group_id integer
    );
```

// e.g collarshape , color , size

```
    CREATE TABLE attribute_group (
        id     integer,
        label varchar(40)
    );
```

Comment: You nedd some post aggreagation filtering,something like GROUP BY name HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN atribute=value THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)>0` and so on for each desired attribute

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do it.

```
SELECT p.id, p.name 
FROM products p
INNER JOIN attributes_products ap ON ap.product_id = p.id
INNER JOIN attributes a ON ap.attibute_id = a.id
WHERE a.id in (15,17,19,20) --list of attributes selected by user
GROUP BY p.id, p.name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT a.attribute_group_id) = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this query will give the desired output

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE id IN (
    SELECT product_id 
    FROM attributes_products 
    GROUP BY product_id
    HAVING (array_agg(attibute_id) @>  ARRAY[90,93])
)


SELECT * FROM products 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT product_id 
    FROM attributes_products 
    GROUP BY product_id
    HAVING (array_agg(attibute_id) @>  ARRAY[90,93])
) AS availableproduts ON products.id = availableproduts.product_id


SELECT * FROM products 
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM attributes_products 
    WHERE products.id = product_id
    GROUP BY product_id
    HAVING (array_agg(attibute_id) @>  ARRAY[90,93])
)
```

The 90,93 is the id of your attributes

The [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/530c0/8) is here

More details on the array function can be found in
[Array Functions and Operators](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-array.html),
[Aggregate Functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-aggregate.html)

Comment: I don't think that works. The product must have at least one matchin in each group  here with more data http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c3ee3c

Comment: @JoErlang sorry, i didn't understood it... can you explain it with an exmaple